# Unknown assignment to parameterized variable

Tags: verilog

Refer to the following code:

```
parameter N=8;

reg [N-1:0] variable;
.
.
\\ stuff
.
.
variable = N'bx;
```

Suppose in some cases we want to set all `N` bits of our vector to x (unknown). How can it be done? The above code does not work, and the error is as follows:

```
Error: ... : near "'b": syntax error, unexpected BASE, expecting ';'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replicated concatenation to set all bits to `x`:

```
variable = {N{1'bx}};
```

For a complete description, refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.12.1 *Replication operator*.